# Multiple Git Repositories out of sync

Tags: git

I have an older remote repository (repo1) that I committed some time ago but has never been pulled into another newer repository (repo2).  I do most of my work on repo2.  When I try to push from repo2 to repo1, it asks me to do a pull from repo1.  I know there would be many conflicts since it is too old.  I don't want to pull from repo1 so I don't have to resolve the conflicts  Does anyone know how to push newer version to repo1?  Should I just delete the repo1 and start from scratch from repo2?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case these are your own repos and you don't care about the contents of repo1, just force push to that repo.

```
cd repo2
# assuming repo1 defined as remote in repo2
git push -f repo1 HEAD:master
```

I personally would create a branch with old stuff on repo1 before pushing new version.

```
cd repo1
git branch old-stuff
cd repo2
git push -f repo1 HEAD:master
```